# convert part of dom element to string with html tags inside of them

Tags: php, html, dom

im in need of converting part of DOM element to string with html tags inside of them.

i tried following but it prints just a text without tags in side.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.pixmania-pro.co.uk/gb/uk/08920684/art/packard-bell/easynote-tm89-gu-015uk.html');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$elements=xpath->query('//table');

foreach($elements as $element)
echo $element->nodeValue;
```

i want all the tags as it is and the content inside tables. can some one help me. it'll be a greate help.

thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[Current solution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php):

```
foreach($elements as $element){
    echo $dom->saveHTML($element);
}
```

Old answer (php < 5.3.6):

1. Create new instance of DomDocument
2. Clone node (with all sub nodes) you wish to save as HTML
3. Import cloned node to new instance of DomDocument and append it as a child
4. Save new instance as html

So something like this:

```
foreach($elements as $element){
    $newdoc = new DOMDocument();
    $cloned = $element->cloneNode(TRUE);
    $newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($cloned,TRUE));
    echo $newdoc->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: oh thanks dev-null-dweller this is exactly what i needed. this saved lot of time. thank you again.

Comment: tnx guy you are realy useful :D

Comment: PLease note @dennis answer below this one here for newer PHP versions.

Comment: Just testing at my end and it appears the '$cloned = $element->cloneNode(TRUE);' line is unnecessary if you put the $element item in the importNode method as opposed to placing the '$cloned' item as you have.

Answer (score 28):

With php 5.3.6 or higher you can use a node in [DOMDocument::saveHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php):

```
foreach($elements as $element){
    echo $dom->saveHTML($element);
}
```