# Retrieve elements with xpath and DOMDocument

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I have a list of ads in the html code below.
What I need is a PHP loop to get the folowing elements for each ad:

1. ad URL (href attribute of `<a>` tag)
2. ad image URL (src attribute of `<img>` tag)
3. ad title (html content of `<div class="title">` tag)

```html
<div class="ads">
    <a href="http://path/to/ad/1">
        <div class="ad">
            <div class="image">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="http://path/to/ad/1/image.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="detail">
                <div class="title">Ad #1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://path/to/ad/2">
        <div class="ad">
            <div class="image">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="http://path/to/ad/2/image.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="detail">
                <div class="title">Ad #2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I managed to get the ad URL with the PHP code below.

```php
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($ads); // the variable $ads contains the HTML code above
$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
$ls_ads = $xpath->query('//a');

foreach ($ls_ads as $ad) {
    $ad_url = $ad->getAttribute('href');
    print("AD URL : $ad_url");
}
```

But I didn't manage to get the 2 other elements (image url and title). Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to get what I need with this code (based on Khue Vu's code) :

```php
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($ads); // the variable $ads contains the HTML code above
$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
$ls_ads = $xpath->query('//a');

foreach ($ls_ads as $ad) {
    // get ad url
    $ad_url = $ad->getAttribute('href');

    // set current ad object as new DOMDocument object so we can parse it
    $ad_Doc = new DOMDocument();
    $cloned = $ad->cloneNode(TRUE);
    $ad_Doc->appendChild($ad_Doc->importNode($cloned, True));
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($ad_Doc);

    // get ad title
    $ad_title_tag = $xpath->query("//div[@class='title']");
    $ad_title = trim($ad_title_tag->item(0)->nodeValue);

    // get ad image
    $ad_image_tag = $xpath->query("//img/@src");
    $ad_image = $ad_image_tag->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

for other elements, you just do the same:

```
foreach ($ls_ads as $ad) {
    $ad_url = $ad->getAttribute('href');
    print("AD URL : $ad_url");
    $ad_Doc = new DOMDocument();
    $ad_Doc->documentElement->appendChild($ad_Doc->importNode($ad));
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($ad_Doc);
    $img_src = $xpath->query("//img[@src]");
    $title = $xpath->query("//div[@class='title']");
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I got an error => Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMXPath::__construct() must be an instance of DOMDocument

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer. The DOMXPath need to initialized with a DOMDocument object.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still get an error => Fatal error: Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I didn't really test the code. Can you try pass in True argument as in: `$ad_Doc->importNode($ad, True)`

Comment: You can refer to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530504/convert-part-of-dom-element-to-string-with-html-tags-inside-of-them) if it is still not correct