# Preg Match in PHP Get Text Between Combo Script and HTML Tags

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, parsing, preg-match

On a WordPress / PHP installation, I need to retrieve a data value consisting of lower and uppercase letters, numbers, and at times a hyphen ( i.e. 11-digit YouTube video id ) from a text ad that is served from a Google DFP ad server.  The output example is below.  In the example, I have the following described data value positions:

```
I-NEED-THIS-1:  This data value is optional and available only when I add it to the ad in Google DFP.

I-NEED-THIS-2:  This data value is required when I create the ad in Google DFP and is the most reliable to always be available.

I-NEED-THIS-3:  This data value is optional and available only when I add it to the ad in Google DFP.
```

Google DFP Output Example:

```
<div class="a-single a-x">
<div id="div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-0">
<script>

    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-0'); });
</script>
<div id="google_ads_iframe_/xxxxxxxx/AD-NAME_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none;">
    <iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/xxxxxxxx/AD-NAME_0">
    </iframe>
</div>
#document
<html>
    <head>
    <script>var xxxxxxx=true;</script>
    </head>
    <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <a href="https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/aclk....." title="I-NEED-THIS-1" target="_blank">
            <span style="color:cccccc">
                <b>I-NEED-THIS-2</b>
            </span>
        </a>
        <span style="color:black">I-NEED-THIS-3</span>
        <br>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried using a version of a preg_match expression described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586779/preg-match-text-in-php-between-html-tags):

```
preg_match("'<span style=\"color:cccccc\"><b>(.*?)</b></span>'si", $source, $match);
```

The result outputs the '...googletag.cmd.push(function()...' script up to the '}'.  It seems to not want to get past this script and locate the pattern.

I have tried other variations, with different patterns such as:

```
'#<a.+?title="([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})[^"]*"[^>]+?>[\S\s]+?</a>#i'

"'<div><div><script><div><iframe><html><body><a><span><b>(.*?)</b></span></a></body></html></iframe></div></script></div></div>'si"
```

and the results do not meet the objective I am searching for.

How can I retrieve this data value and make it available in a variable?  Is preg_match the best method for this on a WordPress / PHP installation?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: You're doing it the hard way. Look into a html parser.

Comment: XPath via `DOMDocument` would be better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547356/retrieve-elements-with-xpath-and-domdocument

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using a version of a preg_match expression described
>   [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586779/preg-match-text-in-php-between-html-tags):
>
> ```
> preg_match("'<span style=\"color:cccccc\"><b>(.*?)</b></span>'si", $source, $match);
> ```

You forgot to cater for the whitespace before `<b>` and after `</b>`. Cf.:

```
preg_match("'<span style=\"color:cccccc\">\s*<b>(.*?)</b>\s*</span>'si", $source, $match);
```