# Output HTML using PHP DOM

Tags: php, domdocument

Im trying to echo HTML using PHP DOM:

```
$doc = new \DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://www.nu.nl");

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

echo $doc->saveHTML($tags);
```

This is getting me a blank page. I also tried:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://www.nu.nl");

$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
  echo $link->getAttribute('href') . '<br />';

}
```

This is getting me the "href" as plain text. I have Googled for hours now and tried many things but I can't figure out how to output HTML as HTML.

Comment: Try `$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://www.nu.nl"));`

Comment: `$tags` is a collection of nodes, not a document that can be saved. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4530728/258674

Comment: Im not trying to output complete document, just the anchors as html `<a href="">anchor</a>`

Comment: Thank you I tried it and it seems to work:) However it kinda 'feels' like a workaround..Are you sure there is now other 'more straight forward' way of doing that?

Comment: If you are using php 5.3.6 or newer, there is quicker way in the same question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16717450/258674

Comment: I actually did use that code from tutorials I found online but it never worked...Now I understand it has to do with my PHP version, thanks again:)

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I just checked it: PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze15 Very weird...I always thought my host had the latest version of everything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a fix that will add the root url for relative links

```
$pageurl = "http://www.nu.nl";
$html = file_get_contents($pageurl);
$html = str_replace('&','&amp;',$html);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $myLink = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if (substr($myLink,0,7) == 'http://') {
        echo '<a href="'.$myLink.'">'.$myLink.'</a><br/>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="'.$pageurl.$myLink.'">'.$myLink.'</a><br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Incredible, this was second on my list to do, thank you very much:)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this doing:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://www.nu.nl");

$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $thelinks[] = '<a href="' . $link->getAttribute('href') . '">' . trim(preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', '', $link->textContent)) . '</a>';
}

var_dump($thelinks);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the foreach

```
echo $doc->saveHTML($link);
```